# "API permission check failed" for admin user

Tags: civicontribute, api, rest

(I'm using version 4.7 based on Wordpress)

When making a REST api call to retrieve a ContributionPage instance, the response tells me that I "require administer CiviCRM". However, the API key is associated with a user in the Administrators group of CiviCRM (this was configured as such using the "group" dropdown in the "New Individual" form of the CiviCRM contacts menu) . For other entities such as "Contact" the call works.

```
    # get contribution page
    resp = requests.get(
        url,
        params=dict(
            entity='ContributionPage',
            action='getsingle',
            api_key='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            key='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            json={"id":1}
        )
    )
    print(resp.text)

{"error_code":"unauthorized","entity":"ContributionPage","action":"getsingle","is_error":1,"error_message":"API permission check failed for ContributionPage\/getsingle call; insufficient permission: require administer CiviCRM"}
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: Are you using Drupal as CMS. And with an user in the Administrators group do you mean the Administrors role in Drupal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must also make the user an admin in the Users panel of the host CMS (wordpress, in this case). It's not sufficient to choose `Administrators` as the value for the "group" dropdown in the "New Individual" form of CiviCRM.